# How to do an automated installation of Ubuntu on 100 Remote machines?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, automated-install, ubuntu-10.04

Help!  I desperately need some advice / help...

I want an automated install (via CD or USB) of Ubuntu 10.04 ...on 100 remote machines located all over the country, using a Kickstart configuration file accessible from my web server.

How do I create the boot CD (or USB)?

How do I specifically add the boot parameters to that boot CD (or USB) to tell it the URL to use for it's automated Kickstart install?

Answer (score 5):

under debian/ubuntu its called preseeding: https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/installation-guide/powerpc/preseed-using.html

You can put the preseed.cfg on CD oder let it load via web. I`m using it in conjunction with cfengine2

Comment: Ubuntu fully supports Kickstart (albeit with a few changes). Under Red Hat, Kickstart locations are specified with a ks= parameter given to the Linux kernel at boot; I don't think Ubuntu is any different. Ubuntu still supports preseeding as part of the kickstart process and adds comamnds to that effect to kickstart.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into [Cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/) to see if it can work for you.  It was primarily developed for RedHat based systems, but it looks like [Ubuntu may be usable](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/wiki/Ubuntu).  Considering that Cobbler supports both PXE as well as boot discs, it should be able to scale to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using FAI (Fully Automatic Installation): 
http://www.informatik.uni-koeln.de/fai/features/

Answer (score 0):

The FAI project has a new $HOME.

http://fai-project.org